# k-NN regression using matlab?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, knn

I have two table namely `Training_table` and `Testing table` each contains two parameters of size say 100. I want to use `k-NN` for training using `training_table` and test the algorithm using 'Testing_table' values.

let us consider, In `Training table`

```
x = [4 5.5 6.5 8 9 10] ; y = [100 200 400 600 900 10000]
```

In `Testing_table`,

```
x1 = [7 8 9 ];  y1 = ?
```

So for given `x1` value what is the estimated value for `y1` ?

I have written code so far ,

```
testing_data = size(test_data,1);
training_data = size(training_data,1);

% absolute distance between all test and training data

dist = abs(repmat(testing_data,1,training_data) - repmat(training_data(:,1)',testing_data,1));

% indicies of nearest neighbors
[~,nearest] = sort(dist,2);
% k nearest
nearest = nearest(:,1:k);

% mode of k nearest
val = reshape(training_data(nearest,2),[],k);
out_data = mode(val,2);
% if mode is 1, output nearest instead
output(output==1) = val(output==1,1);
```

But it seems i am getting wrong. Could anyone suggest or advice on where I am making mistake ?

Comment: Might be a typo in your question, but you reference `trining_data` multiple times in your code

Comment: Yes it is typco mistake, I corrected. Please have a look into code and if possible to help me

Comment: `training_data = size(training_data,1);` also makes no sense. There are many problems with this code, what specifically are you "getting wrong"